# Bootstrap Collapse Button Not Showing Content When Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a CodePen and tried using Bootstrap to make a collapse with a button. I have included the Bootstrap, JQuery, and Popper libraries. The CSS Bootstrap is working because my button is being styled, but when it is clicked it does not display the content. I will include a block of the code as well with a link to the full CodePen. Any suggestions on the project are welcomed as well, but I just really need to know why the collapse is not working. Thanks for reading, and I hope I can get this to work with yall's help!

Button:

```html
<button
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#website-code-container"
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary"
>
  Click Me to See the code used
</button>
```

Content to be displayed:

```
<div id="website-code-container" class="collapse"> ... </div>
```

Link to full CodePen, this will probably help more: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Jacob-Bruce/pen/BEEwgm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the Bootstrap CSS and the Popper JS libraries that you are importing.

Try importing the css from Bootstrap CDN listed at https://getbootstrap.com/

Don't forget to load jQuery before you load bootstrap.js

Here are the links to the CSS and JS for easier access

CSS only

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JS, Popper.js, and jQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can find prior versions of the libraries at https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/legacy/bootstrap/

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I didn't even realize that! Thank you! Do you mind looking at it now and telling me why the two code blocks that are now in the center of the page (temporarily) aren't setting up right. I've made a grid with 30vw in each column and each div is 25vw in width, yet the second block isn't going into the second column. If you don't mind, this is giving me lots of trouble.

Comment: @JakobiBruce You should set `display:grid` on `#website-html` as well. You can "nest" grids by making a grid item a grid container.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I fiddled with it a little bit more and now it doesn't hide the content and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: @JakobiBruce Remove `display:inline-grid` from `#website-code-container`. That prevents it from hiding on collapse. In `#website-html` move `<h1> HTML </h1>` inside the first `<div style="grid-column: 1 / span 1; top:0px;"></div>` block. set `display:grid` instead of `display:block` on `.web-code-block`

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to load files from a local drive. This will not work as filesystem access is not broadly allowed for security reasons.

Instead of these, include the relevant files in your CodePen or in another HTTP-accessible location:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Tech Page.css" />
<script src="E:\Tech Page.js"> </script>
```